# Saving the page state after choosing filters

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have some filters on a web page (checkboxes) and I modify the result list by ajax POST method. Is there a way that somehow I save the page state and send the URL link to someone so they open it in that state? Any help is appreciated.

By the way I'm using Laravel.

Comment: Yes. You need to execute all the javascript/ajax functions at page load event

Comment: But I have parameters (checkboxes) which I have to send in a URL, and I use POST method. How should I do that?

Comment: programatically check the check boxes and pass the checked checkboxes as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters :

```
test.com/page?checkbox1=checked&checkbox2=checked
```

In your Laravel controller you can do this :

```
public function page($request) {
    $checkboxes = array();
    if ($request->has('checkbox1')) {
        $checkboxes[] = true;
    } 
    if ($request->has('checkbox2')) {
        $checkboxes[] = true;
    }
    // ... and so on.

    return view('page', compact('checkboxes'));
}
```

And set your php page like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php checkboxes[$i++] ? 'checked' : '' ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the checkbox as parameter in the URL, and when the user go to your address, check if there is any of your params.
if so - set the checkboxes as you wish

just to get the general idea..

```
function getUrlParams(requested_param){
   //check for params
    return result;
}

if (getUrlParams(myCheckBox)){
      $('#checkbox_on_page').prop( "checked", true );
}
```